# How do i get rid of the not defined/undefined message in my JS console

Tags: javascript

I got my Javascript to talk to my API gateway and my counter keeps going up however on my console it says "undefined", I am not sure how to resolve this issue.
I am not sure what has changed in my code but not i am getting a different message saying instead of the usual "undefined".

```
fetch('https://wwrr7r0kj5.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/')
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(contents =>{
        console.log(contents);
        document.getElementById("visitors").innerHTML = contents
})

 Promise {<pending>}
 VM126:4
 296
```

---

```
 <script>
    fetch('aws api')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(contents => console.log(contents))
     document.getElementById("visitors").innerhtml = content
 </script>
```

---

```
<div>
    <p  style="text-align: center;color: white;"> 
    Visitors: <span id="visitors">0</span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe defining `content` might be a good starting point

Comment: it says `content is not defined`. that means you never defined any variable with the name `content` but you tried to use one. indeed, you can see `document.getElementById("visitors").innerhtml = content` tries to assign the innerhtml to... content... which you never define

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
<script>
    fetch('aws api')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(contents => console.log(contents))
     document.getElementById("visitors").innerHTML = content
 </script>
```

`content` is not defined, you probably meant `contents`, but you have to do it after the promise is resolved:

```
<script>
    fetch('aws api')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(contents =>{
        console.log(contents);
        document.getElementById("visitors").innerhtml = contents
    })
 </script>
```

Comment: I changed "content" to "contents however now it is giving me a "Promise {<pending>}".

Comment: @Fellowmen556 please edit the question with your new code

Comment: @Fellowmen556 what is giving you `Promise{<pending>}`? the console of google chrome?

Comment: Also `innerHTML` instead of `innerhtml`

Comment: @Fellowmen556 be aware that i've not only changed content with contents, but also moved the `innerHTML` line, if you run this code on the console of google chrome, you see `Promise{<pending>}` because is the return value of the last then, not the output of the `console.log` in the last then

Comment: Yes the console of google chrome and i also changed the code on my edit.

Comment: @Berto99 Yes i am. I changed the code on my first comment, you can see the code, promise and the count going up. Only problem is I am not sure why i am getting the promise, sorry for these questions I am a novice at Javascript.

Comment: @Fellowmen556 if you run that code on the google chrome console, the Promise you see is the return object of the last then, you can ignore it, it's just for the debugging purpose

Comment: My "Visitors" number is now working in my HTML and it is going up with my API gateway/Lambda. I appreciate the help @Berto99

Comment: @Fellowmen556 well feel free to mark the answer as correct